# how to build wysiwyg GUI/CMS in web application?

Tags: gui, cms, .net, wysiwyg

Does anyone know if there are any platforms or tools out there to build something like Constant Contact's template and drag and drop page element email builder?

I've been tasked with creating a simplified form of that interface (using .NET, C# and jquery) for specialized web pages, and in poking around in Constant Contact's page source, at least at first it looks just like html elements and jquery leveraging draggable, resize and other css3 attributes. Is this true or are their any tools out there that I can build off of rather than reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports creating any kind of diagram and you can also expose the palette to end users to create a dynamic email builder. I have linked to a generic dynamic builder example and will update this answer with a more specific sample in the next few days.

[Example](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/dashboard/diagrambuilder/default.html)

[image: Diagram Builder]

[Sample](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/puk2xa45)

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

I work for Syncfusion.